# I'm not sure about the last function if its correct

Tags: python

> The main function has been written but you need to fill out other
>   function bodies so that:
>
> The first function takes argument n which signifies the first n terms
>   of the geometric sequence: { 1, 4, 16,64, 256, … }, adds the terms,
>   and returns the total of the terms. An example run with 5 for input
>   would produce: The sum of the geometric series from 1 to 256 is 341
>
> The second function takes argument n which signifies the first n terms of the arithmetic sequence: { 1/3,2/3, 3/3, 4/3, … }, adds the
>   terms, and returns the total to be displayed in the output.
>
> The third function takes a word and returns True if a word is in reverse alphabetical order, False otherwise; examples of reverse
>   alphabetical order words are: won, pi, role, ton.

```
def main():  
    num = int(input('Enter a number of terms: '))
    total = ex4a(num)
    print("The sum of the geometric series from 1 to {} is {}".\
          format(4 ** (num - 1), total))
    total = ex4b(num)
    print("The sum of the arithmetic series from 1/3 to {}/3 is {:.5f}".format(num, total))
    word = input("Enter a word: ")
    isReverse = ex4c(word)
    negation = 'not '
    if isReverse:
        negation = ''
    print("The word {} is {}in reverse alphabetical order".format(word, negation))

def ex4a(num):
    s = 0
    i = 1
    for el in range(num):
        s += i
        i = 4 * i
    return s

def ex4b(num):
    s = 0
    for i in range(num):
        s += i / 3
    return s 

def ex4c(word):
    for i in range(len(word) - 1):
        if word[i] > word[i + 1]:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: Try `wont` or `pit` or `roles` or `tons`. It returns true for these, which is wrong.

Comment: I understand  and thank you @ John Kugelman Are the functions for the other two correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong,  the function return True if word[i]> word[i+1] for every valid i,
In another word, it return False if any word[i]<=word[i+1]

```
def ex4c(word):
    for i in range(len(word) - 1):
        if word[i] <= word[i + 1]:
            return False

    return True
```

Comment: Thank you @He Xiao. Are the other two functions correct?

Comment: range(num),  include  0,1,2....num-1,   so  it should be s += (i+1) / 3,   or  range(1,num+1)